# Flask not showing the entirety of my list

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am creating a web application that scrapes course codes, names, and credits from my schools website. When I "return render_template(...)" I only get back the last course name. But when I run the for loop by itself and tell it to print, I get everything.

I've tried changing the output to equal something else, but that just gives me a list of lists and I want the data to appear as strings.

This is what the code looks like by itself. I spits out the info I want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import csv
import requests 

source = requests.get('https://bulletins.psu.edu/undergraduate/colleges/behrend/digital-media-arts-technology-ba/#programrequirementstext') 

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml') 
course_list = []

for td in soup.find_all("td")[12:162]:
    courseinfo = td.text
    print(courseinfo)
```

This is what my code looks like with flask:

```
@app.route('/digit/')
def digit():
    try:
        source = requests.get('https://bulletins.psu.edu/undergraduate/colleges/behrend/digital-media-arts-technology-ba/#programrequirementstext') 

        soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml') 
        course_list = []

        for td in soup.find_all("td")[12:162]:
            coursename = td.text
            course_list.append(coursename.split())
            print(coursename)

        coursename = coursename
        return render_template("digit.html", coursename = coursename)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("500.html", error = e)
```

And here is the html file:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <p>{{coursename}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Whenever I look at my website and go to the specific page /digit/, I only get "Congress and the Presidency" to show up, which is the last possible thing in the list. I am still pretty inexperienced with flask so I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

`coursename` keeps only last value from list `soup.find_all("td")[12:162]:`.

`print(coursename)` display only one element - but you run it in loop so you get all elements on screen.

---

You have to send `course_list` to template

```
return render_template("digit.html", coursename=course_list)
```

And then you can display it

```
<p>{{coursename}}</p>
```

or you can use loop to format it

```
{% for item in coursename %} 
   <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gave me a list of lists with everything I need.